# Can't install, update or run Meteor after update

Tags: meteor

I have been working with Meteor apps for a few months.  For the first time, anytime I try to run a meteor app, install via (curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh) or run meteor update, I get this error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/meteor/app/meteor/meteor.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

In the past I'd get random js errors and reinstalling would fix, but I cannot even run the installer or update now.  Perhaps it is related to 0.6.  Thanks for any insight!

Comment: I reinstalled node - tried installing meteor again.  Same error, no luck.

Comment: What about restarting/using a fresh terminal?

Comment: You'll have to wait a long while for version 6.0 ;-)

Comment: Version number corrected.

Comment: meteor today (METEOR@1.2.1) continues to error with same issue

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

1. <strike>Install the latest Node via the graphical installer at http://nodejs.org/</strike> EDIT: should not be necessary.
2. <strike>Install Fibers via `sudo npm install fibers@1.0.1 -g` per @Akshat</strike> EDIT: should not be necessary.
3. Delete the file `/usr/local/bin/meteor`
4. Delete the folder `~/.meteor`
5. `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`

Comment: Worked for me without steps 1 & 2. The issue is discussed here too: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1309.

Comment: as of today this worked for me, without steps 1 and 2

Comment: Wow, I answered this question exactly one year before it was accepted :)

Comment: Im getting this error in 0.8.3 and steps 3 and 5 worked great.

Answer (score 8):

I had this happen (again) and did more research.  I ended up doing these two steps to address it:

Remove Meteor:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/meteor /usr/local/bin/meteor
```

Install Meteor:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh
```

Comment: this has happened twice for me... removing the meteor in the bin directory, removing my local .meteor folder, and reinstalling did the trick.  Don't know why it happens though... odd.

Comment: current meteor auto removes its prior install so now just do install step

Comment: works, but that's dumb that we even have to do this.  WTF

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going to my working computer, grabbing the usr/local/bin files and copy/pasting to the non-working computer.  May not be ideal, but it got the job done and I am back coding on both machines.  Thank you Akshat very much for the diligence on this issue!

Paul

Comment: npm is not a mess .. been working just fine for many months ... above issue is meteor related and how to does its layer of package management atop of npm

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your computer/reloading a terminal because the new meteor is installed in a new location too (it looks like yours is still at `/usr/local` instead of `~/.meteor`)

If that doesn't work install fibers with `npm install fibers@1.0.0 -g`.

Comment: Still stuck, but you might be onto something with the path.  I use 2 computers to develop.  All meteor apps are in dropbox and shared.  On the laptop I upgraded to 0.6.  On the computer with this js error I have NOT updated.  If I try, I get the error.  I would still think a simple re-install would work, but no luck.  I did restart my mac too, but same issue.

Comment: Tried npm install and had errors as well:  npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open '/Users/ppedrazzi/.npm/ff36e769-fibers-1-0-0.lock'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open '/Users/ppedrazzi/.npm/ff36e769-fibers-1-0-0.lock']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
...

Comment: try with sudo `npm install fibers@1.0.0 -g`

Comment: done, but meteor install still does not work.  Here was the log from terminal with sudo npm command: npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/1.0.0
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/-/fibers-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers/-/fibers-1.0.0.tgz

> fibers@1.0.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

`darwin-x64-v8-3.14` exists; skipping build
fibers@1.0.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/fibers

Comment: Try `npm cache clean` first if that doesn't help then try reinstall meteor by running sudo -s then calling that curl install script.

Comment: cleaned cache --- same error --- module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^

Comment: Forcibly remove the .lock file at Users/ppedrazzi/.npm/ff36e769-fibers-1-0-0.lock. Also when you initially installed meteor on this machine before did you use npm install on sudo but without the -g perhaps a while ago?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27698/discussion-between-akshat-and-ppedrazzi)

Comment: Could you try also removing node fibers, both the global one and the local one so that its completely fresh when you install meteor? This one should work..

Comment: I'll give it a run Akshat, but could you advise on finding those files?  I am not a node expert.  Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem too.  As it turns out it was a permissions problem with meteor installed on my mac as root.  I reinstalled meteor as the logged in user (with files that are in ~/.meteor).  Everything then worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you bundle / build meteor on one environment (i.e. OS X) and then try to deploy on a different environment (i.e. Ubuntu) it seems that meteor includes the wrong libraries.

I could be wrong in this, in any case I found that uninstalling and re-installing the bcrypt library worked for me (well at least it got me to the point where I get other errors)

Find the directory where `npm list bcrypt` exists, then type `npm remove bcrypt` and then `npm install bcrypt`.

In Meteor V1.2 this is easy to find. In Meteor V1.3 I think it's in `.../bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt`