# OSX, restore installs made with terminal

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

During a long period of time I have installed some apps/scripts with the terminal, many were tests to understand some tools, and now I use just a few of them (very few).

What I would like to accomplish is to wipe them all in order to "restore" OSX installs and, later on I will reinstall the one I need.

I'm not sure I'm using the right terminology, I installed things via terminal like:

- `nodej`
- `meteor`
- `ionic`

And other stuff, some with the use of `curl ...`, others with OSX Installer (NodeJS for example) and others with `cordova` I guess.

How to remove them all?

Comment: You should read the script you `curl`-ed, but it usually just downloads a file into `/usr/local` so you probably can delete everything you recognize under that directory

Comment: Also, consider that some programs will keep data under your home directory (e.g. `~/.meteor`). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686971/how-can-i-completely-uninstall-and-then-reinstall-meteor-js

Comment: I found almost everything in `usr/locall/lib/node_modules`, I deleted the `node_modules` folder. Should that do the trick?

Comment: Mmm... the `node_modules` folders is managed by `npm install`/`npm uninstall`, so the best thing to clean it would have been to run `npm uninstall` for each node package (`npm list --depth=0`).