# Reinstall Active Meteor Project

Tags: meteor

**Background**

I suddenly started getting a Meteor error:

`~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0-1.1b1o7uq++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-x64-v8-4.5/fibers.node is missing. Try reinstalling node-fibers`?`

After extensive searching, I came to the conclusion that there isn't a known, straight-forward solution to this problem.

**Possible Solution**

I created a new Meteor project and that works. This is because it is at the latest version of Meteor, and fibers.node is properly installed in the 1.6 (latest version) directory.
The best solution looks to be removing my live project directory and recreating it with the same name (at Meteor's latest version) and then retrieving all the packages, settings and files (HTML, JS, CSS)

**Question**

What is the best way to do this so that:

1. I preserve all the packages that I have installed (there are many)
2. I preserve all the custom settings that have changed from default
3. I am able to bring all my files (I am assuming this will be simple copy of *.html, *.css and *.js from the original project)

Comment: Is your project in GitHub? Can you re-clone it to your system?

Comment: I have the source code I have written in a git repository + .meteor directory. But I believe I'll still need to install all the packages manually (which is not in git).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the error:

`~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0-1.1b1o7uq++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-x64-v8-4.5/fibers.node is missing. Try reinstalling node-fibers?`

so did not need to go down the reinstalling project path.

I followed the steps in the accepted answer on this thread:

[How can I completely uninstall and then reinstall Meteor.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686971/how-can-i-completely-uninstall-and-then-reinstall-meteor-js)

Specifically:

1. `mv .meteor .meteor.bak`
2. `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/meteor`
3. `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm/`
4. `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`
5. `meteor --version` -> This will pull the required package for the version your project is at.