# Need help: ‘build is not a meteor command“?

Tags: meteor, build, terminal

I’m stuck in a situation where I’m not able to build my meteor app (Version 1.4.3.1) anymore.

When calling

```
meteor build ~/builddir --server subdomain.domain.com
```

I suddenly get the error message

> 'build' is not a meteor command. See 'meteor --help'

I know that any action before the first occurrence of the error is probably the cause.

The last thing I remember was the call of a chain of commands like

```
meteor reset && meteor build ~/_builddir --server subdomain.domain.com && cd ~/_builddir/android && cp release-unsigned.apk release-tosign.apk && jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore .keystorefile release-tosign.apk keystore_alias && mv release-tosign.apk release-signed.apk && ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/zipalign 4 release-signed.apk finalBuild_signed.apk && cd ~/meteordir
```

in Mac Terminal / VS Code terminal. (I don't remember exactly where I started the command chain...

Unfortunately I couldn’t find any similar question here that brings me to a idea or a solution.

After the first occurrence I tried to

```
meteor reset
```

(this is still a known command for meteor), but I got the same error message

I deleted the node_modules and re-installed all packages

`meteor npm i`

but I got the same error message

I tried to update to the meteor version 1.4.3.1 (used in this project)

`meteor update --release 1.4.3.1`

this was not working because cli told me it’s already installed, so I tried to
up- and downgrade via

`meteor update --release 1.4.3.2`

and

`meteor update --release 1.4.3.1`

but I got the same error message

so I started a new installation

`curl "https://install.meteor.com/?release=1.4.3.1" | sh`

but I got the same error message

I alway made the call inside of a meteor project folder, as I always had been doing before.

Comment: before reinstalling the Meteor CLI, did you remove it? 
`sudo rm /usr/local/bin/meteor
rm -rf ~/.meteor`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686971/how-can-i-completely-uninstall-and-then-reinstall-meteor-js

Comment: @HarryAdel 
I did this, but it didn't help, too. 
But maybe it was a problem in the project folder itself. I cloned the project repo again in another folder and the meteor build command was working there. I turned back in original project folder and it was working again. strange but fact. 
It took me 3 days to figure it out and now I fixed it with not knowing the reason.  
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad everything is going smoothly. Good luck with your Meteor Journey! :)

Answer (score 0):

`meteor build` should work on all versions of meteor. You can type `meteor build` and it should complain that it wants a target folder (that should exist)

```
Usage: meteor build <output path> [--debug] [--directory] [--server-only]
          [--mobile-settings settings.json] [--server http://example.com:3000]
```

Comment: Line break is shift+enter here ...

I know that proper description would help better to understand the problem. Unfortunately I can't turn back time and reproduce the action. With knowledge of coming failure in advance it would have been easier. ;-)
I know that the meteor build command SHOULD work, but my issue is, that it didn't. That's the issue! ;-)
I didn't have the problem of any missing parameter or target folder. It was simply that the command `meteor build` didn't work at all.
By the way, the target folder should not already exist. If it not already exists meteor will create it.