# Meteor 0.9 Modulus deployment doesn't work - "Cannot find module 'fibers'"

Tags: javascript, meteor, modulus.io

When trying to deploy a newly created Meteor (0.9) app I always get this error message in the Modulus logs:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/data/2/programs/server/boot.js:1:75)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

what I did was:

- installing meteor with [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851923/cant-install-update-or-run-meteor-after-update) steps
- executing [these](https://modulus.io/codex/meteor_apps) steps for modulus setup

but even after trying the solution of the question ["Can't install, update or run Meteor after update"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851923/cant-install-update-or-run-meteor-after-update) I can't get it running.

anyone a guess what's wrong here?

Comment: Just deployed an app and getting the same issue. Have you had any developments?

Comment: @onepixelsolid what do you mean with "developments"?

Comment: Suggesting you roll back to the version of Meteor which you originally wrote the app. 0.9 is relatively new, and a lot of things break.

Comment: i am also getting the same issue .. is the issue resolved ??

Comment: @naveen for it works with the modulus CLI tool 1.1.1, try to update and deploy again with "modulus deploy"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This may have something to do with the new architecture of the meteor bundle (the process which converts a Meteor app to a regular Node.js app).

In Meteor < 0.9 you had to run npm install at the root of the bundle to get npm modules installed, now you have to cd in programs/server first, as stated in the README :

```
This is a Meteor application bundle. It has only one external dependency:
Node.js 0.10.29 or newer. To run the application:

  $ (cd programs/server && npm install)
  $ export MONGO_URL='mongodb://user:password@host:port/databasename'
  $ export ROOT_URL='http://example.com'
  $ export MAIL_URL='smtp://user:password@mailhost:port/'
  $ node main.js

Use the PORT environment variable to set the port where the
application will listen. The default is 80, but that will require
root on most systems.

Find out more about Meteor at meteor.com.
```

Modulus developed a tool called `demeteorizer` which is supposed to automate this process of converting a Meteor app to a Node.js app, and it's possible that they have not yet modified the tool to account for 0.9 changes.

Comment: They have though → https://twitter.com/OnModulus/status/505493207816630272 and I can confirm it's working for me now.

Comment: with the modulus tool version 1.1.1 it works just with "modulus deploy"

Comment: where is programs/server?

Comment: You have to build a bundle first by typing `meteor build --directory ../build` in your meteor project directory. Then the directory you need to `cd` into to `npm install` is `../build/bundle/programs/server`

Answer (score 13):

After building your bundle, run the following:

```
cd <bundle dir>/programs/server
sudo npm install
```

That will install fibers into the bundle and that fixed it for me.  Hope this works for you!

Comment: Sounds like it helped. Just I have an other error message now: Meteor requires Node v0.10.29 or later. Hopefully I understand the later one ,-)

Comment: @Pivert follow the How To Install Using a PPA section on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but with building from the Meteorite Heroku buildpack.  To save you the frustration of finding an updated buildpack, if you go [here](https://github.com/djhi/heroku-buildpack-meteorite), you can use this buildpack that has the updates for Meteor 0.9.x. Thanks @djhi.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i also tried it with the meteorite heroku build pack, but apparently it didn't support 0.9.x back then.

Comment: Take a look at this for 0.9.x: https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell if this is the same problem, however my app is now running after removing the 'spiderable' package.

Comment: it's a fresh meteor app, so there's no spiderable package