# Meteor Heroku App Crash after deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku, meteor

After deploying the app to heroku, my app fails to start. I think this might be to do with the build pack and latest version of meteor 0.9.x?

Where should I start to debug this from?

```
2014-09-02T05:02:58.848513+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-09-02T05:03:05.407436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node .meteor/heroku_build/app/main.js`
2014-09-02T05:03:06.578829+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2014-09-02T05:03:06.579092+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2014-09-02T05:03:06.586422+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2014-09-02T05:03:06.578419+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-09-02T05:03:06.586423+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-09-02T05:03:06.579105+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2014-09-02T05:03:06.586414+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'fibers'
2014-09-02T05:03:06.586426+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2014-09-02T05:03:06.586420+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2014-09-02T05:03:06.586428+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/boot.js:1:75)
2014-09-02T05:03:06.586429+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2014-09-02T05:03:06.586431+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2014-09-02T05:03:06.586432+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2014-09-02T05:03:06.586434+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2014-09-02T05:03:06.586436+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2014-09-02T05:03:07.681468+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-09-02T05:03:07.680466+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581301/meteor-0-9-modulus-deployment-doesnt-work-cannot-find-module-fibers

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough points to leave a comment to your post, but this will solve your problem even if it doesn't answer your question. This question hasn't been answered in over a month so why not?

You are correct. Many popular buildpacks are having trouble with meteor 0.9.x; I'm not a good enough programmer to understand why or what the spefic issues are. I'm also not sure why the buildpack linked below works, but it does.

https://github.com/djhi/heroku-buildpack-meteorite.git

Hopefully this will help other meteor developers suffering from the same issues even if this post doesn't answer the question.

EDIT - updated post per @jww's comment; my post still doesn't provide an answer but it does provide a solution.

EDIT 2 - This buildpack is not longer working for me. See my comment below. The following is working again for me:
https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse

Comment: This buildpack just stopped working for me recently. After some searching, I got the buildpack linked below to work. This is a freaking nightmare... ugh
https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. This because of the node version, Meteor support **node 0.10.36** or higher version

I just followed my steps it work's well

Create meteor application and make sure it's running without any error.

```
meteor create todo
```

Go to todo app directory

```
cd todo
```

Add and commit with GIT

```
git init
git add .
git commit -am "Initial commit"
```

Create heroku app with buildpack

```
heroku create --buildpack  https://github.com/kannans/heroku-buildpack-meteor.git
```

Add meteor heroku configurations

```
heroku addons:add mongolab:sandbox
heroku config:add MONGO_URL=<mangolap url> 
heroku config:add ROOT_URL=https://herokuappname.herokuapp.com/
```

For MONGO_URL. Just create account & get url from  https://mongolab.com/

Push your changes to Heroku.

```
git push heroku master
```

My meteor app in Heroku :) https://herokuappname.herokuapp.com/