# Why is meteor no longer working? `throw new Error('`'+ modPath+ '.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibe`

Tags: node.js, meteor, node-fibers, fiber

I'm running Meteor 1.3.2.4 and Node v4.4.3 . All my projects no longer load and show the following error.  At first it was a `Cannot find modules fibers` error for which I did `meteor build --directory ../build` and `cd .meteor/local/build/programs/server` and npm install [which I saw here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581301/meteor-0-9-modulus-deployment-doesnt-work-cannot-find-module-fibers)
and then the error changed into this:

```
Massimo-2:Meteor tzikas$ cd newProj/          
Massimo-2:newProj tzikas$ ls
client      package.json    server
Massimo-2:newProj tzikas$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/Documents/TzikasCode/Meteor/newProj ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
W20160526-19:24:37.373(-4)? (STDERR)          
W20160526-19:24:37.374(-4)? (STDERR) /Users/tzikas/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.109e4rj++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:16
W20160526-19:24:37.374(-4)? (STDERR)    throw new Error('`'+ modPath+ '.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibe
W20160526-19:24:37.374(-4)? (STDERR)          ^
W20160526-19:24:37.375(-4)? (STDERR) Error: `/Users/tzikas/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.109e4rj++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/bin/darwin-x64-v8-3.14/fibers.node` is missing. Try reinstalling `node-fibers`?
W20160526-19:24:37.375(-4)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tzikas/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.109e4rj++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/fibers.js:16:8)
W20160526-19:24:37.375(-4)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
W20160526-19:24:37.375(-4)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
W20160526-19:24:37.375(-4)? (STDERR)     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
W20160526-19:24:37.375(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
W20160526-19:24:37.376(-4)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
W20160526-19:24:37.376(-4)? (STDERR)     at require (module.js:380:17)
W20160526-19:24:37.376(-4)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tzikas/Documents/TzikasCode/Meteor/newProj/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:1:75)
W20160526-19:24:37.377(-4)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
W20160526-19:24:37.377(-4)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
=> Exited with code: 8
```

I tried [npm uninstalling and reinstalling fibers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327088/meteor-bundle-fails-because-fibers-node-is-missing) as well,  in the server folder, but to no avail.

Also meteor seems to be working fine on my laptop, running the same versions, just not my desktop.

Comment: I just uninstalled and reinstalled meteor in the end http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686971/how-can-i-completely-uninstall-and-then-reinstall-meteor-js

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure what the problem was exactly but completely uninstalling and resinstallling meteor did the trick thank god
[How can I completely uninstall and then reinstall Meteor.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686971/how-can-i-completely-uninstall-and-then-reinstall-meteor-js)