# Meteor: connect Unknown system errno 64 when running Meteor update

Tags: meteor

I am trying to update my Meteor repository to 0.9.0 but when I ran 'Meteor update' it says could not connect to server, are you sure you are online?

I was online so I searched the error and found this stackoverflow and follow the instructions:

[Can't install, update or run Meteor after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851923/cant-install-update-or-run-meteor-after-update)

Now when I try running meteor update in the meteor folder I get the error:

```
Error connecting to package server: Network error: wss://packages.meteor.com/websocket: connect Unknown system errno 64
Warning: could not connect to package server

/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.26.p03e91++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
[Offline: Error: connect Unknown system errno 64]
```

And now I am stuck. I have no idea how to get my app running on the computer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

I restarted my computer and got rid of the error I was reporting in this post but I am back to the original error: When running Meteor update it reports

```
Can't contact the update server. Are you online?
This project is already at Meteor 0.8.3, the latest release
installed on this computer.
```

Not sure what to do about that...

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Restart the computer. Nothing else needed. Just restarted the computer and now it works. I think upon restart the OS might have updated the location of certain files or something like that. Not sure but a restart worked.