# Trying to run Meteor after updating to 0.9.0 and getting error: Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:3001]

Tags: meteor

I've been trying to get my app working after upgrading to 0.9.0 and I have been experiencing weird issues.

First I cloned my repository onto this computer which was at 0.8.3 Then When I ran Meteor update I got error:

```
Can't contact the update server. Are you online?
This project is already at Meteor 0.8.3, the latest release
installed on this computer.
```

So I following the instructions here: [Can't install, update or run Meteor after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851923/cant-install-update-or-run-meteor-after-update)

But even after that I got the same error. So then I just changed the release version number in the .meteor folder to 0.9.0 and ran meteor update and it update the app.

Then I ran mrt migrate-app, and migrated all the packages successfully.

Now when I run 'Meteor' I get this error:

```
Ferozes-iMac:Bookmarks Feroze$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/Desktop/Meteor_Bookmark/Bookmarks ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Starting MongoDB... |
/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:3001]
    at Object.Future.wait (/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
    at Object.exports.waitForOne (/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:53:25)
    at yieldingMethod (/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-mongo.js:209:25)
    at initiateReplSetAndWaitForReady (/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-mongo.js:382:7)
    at launchMongo (/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-mongo.js:494:9)
    at _.extend._startOrRestart (/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-mongo.js:581:19)
    at _.extend.start (/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-mongo.js:547:10)
    at _.extend.start (/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-all.js:130:24)
    at Object.exports.run (/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-all.js:275:10)
    at main.registerCommand.name [as func] (/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/commands.js:219:17)
    at /Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/main.js:1212:23
    - - - - -
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/unipackages/mongo-livedata/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:536:74)
    at emit (events.js:106:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/unipackages/mongo-livedata/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:150:15)
    at emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/Feroze/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.25.1761nat++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/unipackages/mongo-livedata/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:516:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:440:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Appreciate the help

---

UPDATE

To help debug, I create a new user account, installed meteor, cloned my project. And then ran meteor  update. And this is what I get:

```
Ferozes-iMac:Bookmarks Nearpoint$ meteor update
Installing Meteor 0.9.0.1:
 * 'meteor' build tool (version 8301fde275)

Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
This project is at the latest release which is compatible with your
current package constraints.
```

That isn't normal, it should ask me to migrate the app?

Here is my packages file:

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

standard-app-packages
npm
iron-router
spin
jade
coffeescript
stylus
bootstrap-3
font-awesome
accounts-password
jquery-ui
select2
jquery-masonry
accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
bootstrap-errors
http
moment
accounts-google
jquery
bootstrap3-datetimepicker
filepicker
meds
kadira
jquery-ui-bootstrap
flash-messages
```

Here is smart.json

```
{
  "packages": {
    "iron-router": {
      "version": "0.8.2"
    },
    "spin": {},
    "jade": {},
    "font-awesome": {},
    "jquery-ui": {},
    "bootstrap-3": {},
    "select2": {},
    "jquery-masonry": {},
    "accounts-ui-bootstrap-3": {},
    "bootstrap-errors": {},
    "moment": {},
    "bootstrap3-datetimepicker": {},
    "filepicker": {},
    "meds": {},
    "kadira": {},
    "jquery-ui-bootstrap": {},
    "flash-messages": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
iron-router
```

with

```
iron:router@0.9.1
```

in your packages file.

Comment: thanks so much. I was still having issues what trying to use meteor update even after manually changing the file and using meteor update. But I removed the cmather iron router at 0.8.2 and used the meteor add iron:router and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing to get it working.

Starting off with a working Meteor app at version 0.8.3,

1) I first manually changed the release file version to 0.9.0 as simply running 'meteor update' did not work to update meteor to 0.9.0.

2) After manually changing the release file number to 0.9.0 then run 'meteor update'

3) After meteor updates, make sure you update meteorite with

```
npm install -g meteorite

or if you need sudo access

sudo -H npm install -g meteorite
```

4) After meteorite successfully updates then run 'mrt migrate-app'. Work out any bugs it may report. My app had packages that were incompatible with the migration so I had to remove them from the smart.json file first and then run 'mrt migrate-app' again. Run the command until is sucessfully completes.

5) Then run 'meteor' and the server should start. It might still complain about incompatible packages. You should check atmosphere package website for package that are working with 0.9.0 and install those and remove any packages meteor complains about.

This is how I got my app working on 0.9.0